# How to write Python type hint when a function change its paramter's type

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

Let's say I have a Python function which expect input a `List[str]`, and change it into `List[int]`

```
def data_cleaning(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] = int(data[i])
```

How should I add type hint to this function? Should I write...

- `def data_cleaning(data: typing.List[str]) -> None`
- `def data_cleaning(data: typing.List[int]) -> None`
- `def data_cleaning(data: typing.List[typing.Union[str, int]]) -> None`

Any of these?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a bigger problem. As far as static typing goes, changing a `List[str]` into a `List[int]` is a type error. Imagine what it would look like at the call site:

```
x: List[str] = ['1', '2', '3']
data_cleaning(x)
```

Now the `x` variable holds a `List[int]` when it was supposed to only hold values of type `List[str]`.

There is no correct annotation for "changes `List[str]` to `List[int]`". At best, you can annotate `data` as `List[Any]`, and call the function with an argument annotated as `List[Any]`.